# Use Regex replace character but dont replace escaped character

Tags: c#, regex, replace, escaping

I have a string and I want use `Regex` to replace `[` to `{`, but if `[` is escaped, ignore it, like this:

```
abc[def\[ghi
```

to

```
abc{def\[ghi
```

How can I do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the [ you want to replace always have a space before it? If so just replace " [" with " {".

Comment: Is that really the actual rule? Shouldn't the rule rather be "Replace unescaped brackets with braces"?

Comment: Also, what about strings like `[foo] bar {baz\[bam}`? Would you really want the result to be `{foo] bar {baz\[bam}`?

Comment: What about this `[abc[efg[hij` .. should that be: `{abc{efg[hij` or just replace the first one, so it becomes `{abc[efg[hij`?

Comment: @MohamedTarek: I want replace all, TimPietzcker gave me right solution! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(?<=     # Make sure that this is true before the start of the match:
     (?<!\\)   # There is no single backslash,
     (?:\\\\)* # but if there are backslashes, they need to be an even number.
    )          # End of lookbehind assertion.
    \[         # Only then match a bracket", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```